# List, map function based on a condition

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, map

I have the following list:

```
input = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
   1, 0, 1}}
```

there are two conditions:

- When a '0' is followed by '1', the value of '0' change to .5
- When a '1' is followed by '0', the value of '0' change to .5

the desired output is:

```
output = [{{0, 0, 0, .5, 1, 1, 1, .5, 1, .5, 0, .5, 1, 1, .5, 1, .5, 
    0, .5, 1, .5, 1}, {.5, 1, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1, .5, 0, 0, 0, .5, 1, 
    1, .5, 1, .5, 0, .5, 1, .5, 1}, {1, 1, .5, .5, 1, 1, 1, .5, 0, 0, 
    0, .5, 1, 1, .5, 1, 0, 0, .5, 1, .5, 1}}]
```

Who has a suggestion how to get the desired output

Comment: should desired[[3]] be `{1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) and pattern matching:

```
input //. {{x___, 0, 1, y___} :> {x, 0.5, 1, y}, {x___, 1, 0, y___} :> {x, 1, 0.5, y}}
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, **0.5**, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}}

Note that there is a slight difference between this and your suggested output, highlighted in bold. As @Nasser received this result by his method as well, I suspect that the original suggested `output` was in error.

Comment: Tricky. I tried it similar inside `Cases` but only one substitution is made. What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: `/.` only tries to replace once per complete match, as I understand, so since each list matches `{x___, 1, 0, y___}` or the other it only undergoes one substitution each. `//.` explicitly retries until no matches remain. I think `Cases` works more like `/.` in that respect.

Comment: Thanks, I have to think about it.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use a combination of [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html) and [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html):

```
f = Map[SequenceReplace[{{0, 1} -> Sequence[.5, 1], {1, 0} -> Sequence[1, .5]}]], 

FixedPoint[f, input]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 
>     0.5, 1, 0.5, 1},
>   {0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1,
>      1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1},
>   {1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 
>     0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}}

You can also use [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) in place of `FixedPoint`:

```
Nest[f , input, 2] == %
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

For a rewriting problem, use rewriting explicitly:

```
input //. {
    {x___, 0, 1, y___} -> {x, 0.5, 1, y}, 
    {x___, 1, 0, y___} -> {x, 1, 0.5, y}
}
(*
    {{0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}, 
    {0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1,1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}, 
    {1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "functional" way to do it. But an old fashioned loop and few if's. But it gives the result you show

```
foo[input_List] := Module[{n, i, current, next, before},
  n = Length[input];

  (*handle edge cases*)
  If[n == 1, Return[input, Module]];
  If[n == 2, 
   Return[If[input[[1]] == 0 && input[[2]] == 1, {0.5, 1}, 
     If[input[[2]] == 0 && input[[1]] == 1, {1, 0.5}, input]], 
    Module]];

  (*general case for list of length \[GreaterEqual] 3*)
  Table[
   current = input[[i]];
   If[i == 1,
    If[input[[i]] == 0 && input[[i + 1]] == 1, 0.5, input[[i]]]
    ,
    If[i == n, 
     If[input[[n]] == 0 && input[[n - 1]] == 1, 0.5, input[[n]]]
     ,
     before = input[[i - 1]]; 
     next = input[[i + 1]];
     If[current == 0 && next == 1, 0.5, 
      If[current == 0 && before == 1, 0.5, current]]
     ]
    ],
   {i, 1, Length[input]}
   ]
  ]


input = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1}};
```

Now map `foo` on the input

```
 result = foo[#] & /@ input
```

gives

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 
  0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1,
   1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 
  0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1}}
```

I suspect there might be a shorter way to do this if one works harder on it.